# Class object property model is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am building a to-do-list project as a practice. It has one relationship to the Member model and the Member model has many relationships to 'to-do-list'

Member controller create method works without any issue but the to-do-list controller throws model state is invalid on Member object property of to-do-list

ToDoList

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace To_Do_List.Models
{
    public class ToDoList
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "To Do List Item cannot be longer than 200 characters.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }


        public string Priority { get; set; }
       
        public int AssignToId { get; set; }

        
        public Member AssignTo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.")]
        [RegularExpression("^(Completed|Not Completed)$", ErrorMessage = "The status must be Completed or Not Completed")]
        public string Status { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

Member

```
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;

namespace To_Do_List.Models
{
    public class Member
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public ICollection<ToDoList> ToDoLists { get; set; }
        
        
    }
}
```

create method of `to do list` controller

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,Description,DueDate,Priority,AssignToId,AssignTo, Status")] ToDoList toDoList)
  {
            


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(toDoList);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            ViewData["AssignToId"] = new SelectList(_context.Members, "Id", "Id", toDoList.AssignToId);
            return View(toDoList);
  }
```

View method of `to do list`

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model To_Do_List.Models.ToDoList

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>ToDoList</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DueDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DueDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DueDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Priority" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Priority" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Priority" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Status" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Status" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Status" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: How are you sending request from your view could you please attach that part? View is crucial to check.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I didn't send any request from view.  `public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }`

Comment: Than, hows the request sending? If I understand correctly, you would like to bind `Member` along with list of `ToDoList` together right? If so your binding is not correct as well. However, its important to see, how the request are sending.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, Yes, I would like to bind the `Member` along with list of `ToDoList`. I added my `view method and create.cshtml` I haven't sent anything from the view method. Do I need to send anything from the view method?

Comment: Wait a while, I am investigating your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> Member controller create method works without any issue but the
> to-do-list controller throws model state is invalid on Member object
> property of to-do-list

Well, I have succssfully reproducced your issue and your `ModelState.IsValid` false is logical. Because, when you leave `public Member AssignTo { get; set; }` with [default annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0) it means required. whilist, you haven't pass any property from your view consequently, your bindings always be `false` as you have defined it into the `[Bind]` property that is `AssignTo` However, value has not been pass to it.

**How to resolve:**

In this scenario, you either has to pass `AssignTo` to your `create action` or make it nullable using `?` annotation as following:

```
 public Member? AssignTo { get; set; }
```

**Note:** If you don't want to set `AssignTo`  as nullable then you have to pass all property value from your view as following:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AssignTo.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="AssignTo.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AssignTo.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Here, I am passing only `AssignTo.Name` you have to pass rest of the values.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#model-state).

Comment: No wait, I found another issue, I am updating the answer within a while.

Comment: Now you can have try and it would resolve your issue